# How to replace updated source code of Android app with existing app source code in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace, developer-tools

Our Android app is updated with more features and the developer sent us the updated source code. My question is How to replace the existing source code in the eclipse or workspace with the updated source code, so that the app works with new features and updated with new source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer to your question is this.

1.Delete the the existing code.

2.then open eclipse `File->Import->Android existing projects`

3.click o.k and give the path of your updated code.

I think this would help.

Comment: will the imported project can be signed with old password and same certificates

Comment: yes certificates will be the same but for the password you have to ask it to  your developer.

Comment: doing this process the app can be submitted to the play Store as new version?

Comment: Yes I will work for you.And if you like it you can accept my answer

Comment: As long as you the app has the same certificate, and has the same name (com.thisname.thatname) then yes it will be allowed on the playstore as an "update"